# .clang-format file for editing of c++ code: is clang version relevant?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I have a .clang-format file in my source directory for c++ code editing.

The file has entries like

```
AccessModifierOffset: -2

AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Left
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: true
```

I already saw such a file in bigger libraries coming with a header

```
#
# The clang-format (Clang 11) style file used by our library 
#
```

My question is if a .clang-format file is bound to a specific version of clang? In other words, does it matter whether I have clang-6 or clang-16 installed or is the file generic for all clang versions?

Comment: The file may well be auto-generated, see the official docs (and then possibly edited). I've never had issues with the file being specific to a particular clang version. What I _have_ had plenty of issues with is that each version of clang-format you use is subtly different from previous versions, so on a large shared code base, it matters that everyone uses the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the different clang-format versions may have different format result. We already met that issue in our project.